# Running multiple task using web worker in Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, typescript, web-worker

I am trying to read multiple JSON files simultaneously and create a single array using the data available in the files and do some processing with the created data array in the Node.js server.

I would like to read these files and do the processing tasks simultaneously using web workers.

I read a few interesting tutorials and articles about the subject, but no one clearly explains how to process simultaneous tasks using web workers.

They talk about running a single separated task from the main thread. But I need to do multiple tasks at once.

I also know that creating multiple workers is not recommended according to the documentation of Node.js.

Maybe I have a misunderstanding of how the web worker is functioning or with the implementation in order to perform multiple tasks.

I also tried this great library Thread.js - https://threads.js.org/ still the documentation is unclear about running multiple tasks.

Can anyone please explain what is the way of implementing this kind of work with best practice along with the pros and cons?

I would prefer implementing the vanilla JS solution other than using a library so the explanation would also be a reference to readers.

Also if possible someone can explain the usage of the Thread.js library as well for future reference.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Nodejs native cluster module supports spawning multiple node processes to run some tasks. You can share any info with the main process thread.
You can spawn many as you want as long your hardware / software supports it.
https://nodejs.org/api/cluster.html

Comment: Hi @kalle, Thank you very much for sharing the information. I will go through the documentation and try it.

Answer (score 2):

As I'm sure you have read, the node is single-threaded, so running transactions in parallel is not going to work, even with worker threads as they are not designed to run in parallel.

A worker thread is more for longer, more process intense functions that you want to pass off and not block the main event loop, so if you think of it in terms of uploading and processing an image.. well we don't really want to hang up the entire event loop while the image is processed, so we can pass it off to a worker thread and it will tell the event loop when it's done, and it will return the response.

I think what you may be looking to do is just create a promise, so you would have a promise and say an array of the JSON file name like ["file1.JSON", "file2.JSON"] Then in your promise you would loop over, read the contents and 'return' the JSON object, insert or concat the main array variable.

Once the promise resolves, you would use the

```
.then(()=>{ //Do you processing of the full array })
```

Comment: Thank you for your explanation and very interesting answer, But I will wait for some more verbose explanations. i.e. not limited to reading files, but after reading the files, if need to index the data using a library like flexsearch - https://github.com/nextapps-de/flexsearch - or re-organize filtering/ modifying the main array to produce a new array processing the data and return the result. The process may take some time according to the number of files and the size of the data, etc.

Comment: It seems like `Promise.all` would work well for reading the array of files. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example with a library ([node-worker-threads-pool](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-worker-threads-pool)).

Thread/worker management is a complex endeavor, and I would not recommend trying to have some generic solution. Even the library I'm suggesting may not be correct.

```js
// sample.js
const { StaticPool } = require('node-worker-threads-pool');

const start = async function () {

    const staticPool = new StaticPool({
        size: 4,
        task: async function(n) {
            const sleep = async function (ms) {
                return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
            }
            console.log(`thread ${n} started`);
            await sleep(1000 * n);
            return n + 1
        }
    });

    // start 4 workers, each will run asynchronously and take a longer time to finish
    for (let index = 0; index < 4; index++) {
        staticPool.exec(index)
            .then((result) => {
                console.log(`result from thread pool for thread ${index}: ${result}`);
            })
            .catch((err) => console.error(`Error: ${err}`));
    }
}

start();
```

I ran this in npm using `node sample.js`

As discussed in the other answer, it may not be useful (in terms of performance) to do this, but this example shows how it can be done.

The library also has examples where you give the tasks specific work.

Comment: Hi, Thank you for the answer and for introducing another library that can give it a try, sometimes the solution will fit according to the requirement. Will see what else the community has for this kind of question as an explanation. I need a great description for later use as a good reference for newbies.